# Solving a Bernoulli Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following Bernoulli Differential Equations
$$ty'+y=-ty^2$$

Transform it into a linear equation and then solve it.

What i tried

Dividing by $y^2$, i got

$$(t/y^2)y'+y^{-1}=-t$$

Then i let $u=y^{-1}$

Hence $u'=-y^{-2}y'$

Substituting both expressions into the ODE, i got

$$-tu'+u=-t$$

Am i on the right track, and how to continue form here. Could anyone please explain.

Comment: Whatever there is a trivial solution $y_t=0$ there which you may have looked over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
If $t\ne0$ divide both sides by $(-t)$ and we get
$$u'-\frac1tu=1$$
And what if $t=0$?
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I use the integrating factor method. My integreating factor is thus $u(t)=1/t$. Then i multiply the LHS and the RHS of the expression by the integreating factor, getting $$u/t=\int 1/t dt$$. Which then becomes $u=tln(t)+ct$ after simplification. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So the result is $u(t)=(\ln|t|+C)t$

Comment: Well I suggest you use $\ln|t|$ instead of $\ln(t)$ to avoid loss of generality.